Insert all the dates and calculate a field based on the other fields
I have a scenario where we need to implement a logic to include the missing dates based on the other fields and compute the value
Any suggestion on how to implement the scenario
Input data:
date       | one | two | derived | Formula
------------------------------------------
2020-08-15 | A     | 1.0     | 0 | null
2020-08-14 | A     | 2.0     | 0 | null
2020-08-15 | B     | 4.0     | 0 | null
2020-08-14 | B     | 5.0     | 0 | null
null       | C     | null    | 1 | (A+B)/2
null       | D     | null    | 1 | (B)*2

Expected Output:
date       | one | two |
------------------------
2020-08-15 | A     | 1.0
2020-08-14 | A     | 2.0
2020-08-15 | B     | 4.0
2020-08-14 | B     | 5.0
2020-08-15 | C     | 2.5(1.0+4.0)/2
2020-08-14 | C     | 3.5(2.0+5.0)/2
2020-08-15 | D     | 8.0(4.0)*2
2020-08-14 | D     | 10.0(5.0)*2

From the above it can be seen that the products C and D are computed fields which will not have any dates but only the Formula on how to derive. the dates from which the Products in the formula exists needs to be filled in for both Product C and D
In the above case Product C is associated with A,B so all the dates that exists for A,B should be populated.
Product D is associated with only B so all the dates that exists for B should be used to populated for Product D.
Please help. Thanks in advance
